# exit the process once Jar is completed

Tags: java, shell, processbuilder, exit-code

I am using process builder to execute my Runnable Jar using shell script in my Java Program.
Below is my Java code

```
 command = "t4essh -l " + username +  " -p " + password + " -a 2500 -A password " + host + " \" cd " +"/data/jblext/JBLOADER.OUT" +";./test.sh "+tablename+" \"";
         Runtime rtt = Runtime.getRuntime();
          Process pr = rtt.exec(command);
          OutputStream obj = pr.getOutputStream();

            ByteArrayOutputStream byte1=new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            obj.write(byte1.toByteArray());  
            String s=byte1.toString();  
                  System.out.println("output from .sh " + s);


          System.out.println("command"+ command);
          boolean processFinish = false;

             while(!processFinish) {
                 try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                     int exitVal = pr.exitValue();
                     System.out.println("Process"+exitVal);
                     System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);

                     if (exitVal == 0)

                         {System.out.println("testet");
                         processFinish = true;}

                     else
                     {System.out.println("sysysyyyyyyyy");
                         processFinish = false;
                     }

                 } catch (Throwable t) {
                     processFinish = false;
                     System.out.println("catch"+ t);
                    /* GENERAL.println("Waiting for process finish : " + command);
                     System.out.println("Waiting for process finish : " + command);*/
                    // t.printStackTrace();
                 }

             }
 }
             catch (Exception e) {
                  BufferedWriter bw = null;
                    System.err.println("Error executing parse command " + e.getMessage());

             }
```

I am having my shell script in Linux server. Below is the piece of code

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "test"
java -jar Manager.jar $1
```

When i execute my java program getting with

```
catchjava.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
```

My Runnable jar will run for at least 2 minutes. How do I exit once the runnable jar is completed?

Comment: Call `pr.waitFor();` and `System.exit()`?

Comment: Dear Elliott, If i used System.exit() whole Java application endsup. i want to exit the particular process builder once it is executed. Any idea on that...

Comment: Yes. Use `pr.waitFor();`, that will wait for the process to end. It actually returns an `int` indicating the *exit* code of your process.

Comment: Elliott, pr.waitFor() is waiting for a long time but it is not exiting the application.

Answer (score 0):

`System.exit()` is exit the whole system, not current process.
I think, there are two common way to exit the current process(I mean `Method`).

```
1. Use `return`
2. Use `throw Exception`
```

Example :

```
    public void doSomething() {

        while(your-condition) {
            if(isOK()) {
                throw new Exception(); -> It will exit from doSomething() method;
                throw new MyException(); -> It will exit from doSomething() method;
                return; -> It will exit from doSomething() method;
                break;  -> It will exit while loop;
                System.exit(); -> It will exit from the whole system;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you want to call [Process.destroy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29);

```
pr.destroy(); // <-- this will "kill" the running program...
              // I'm not sure what it did to you.
```